# Google Chrome Toolbar Searching Not working

Tags: google-chrome

When I type in the toolbar like "this is a test". I would think it would do a google search for this. Instead for me just goes to "google" with no search term. To make things worse if I try to type in google it usually forces my cursor to the url bar to type it there.

So I get a never endless loop.

Comment: Does the URL shown when you land on the google page have something like "www.google.com/webhp?" at the front of it?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of the issue? Might help clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix.

Go to settings -> manage search engines

Scroll to the bottom and make a new Google search with the following

http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&channel=rcs

Make it default.

This fixed it for me.